# Why Itunes keeps stubbornly grey my songs out, while they are still available on apple music?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I can imagine a few reasons why some songs become greyed out and not available for listen/donwload: for instance song removed by owner from apple music, or it was probably rearranged to another album. While my sense of fairness revolts when it happens to my beloved songs, I'm pretty sure apple has it explained somewhere deep in their user agreement.

But what logic is behind the situation when song keeps getting greyed short time after I added it to my library, while it hasn't been removed, rearranged and I can totally add it one more time, just to find it greyed out again after a while?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't answer your question with any degree of certainty, but I recommend switching to Spotify! It is much more satisfactory than Apple Music, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Checkout this website for fix. https://appletoolbox.com/2016/05/itunes-songs-greyed-how-to-fix/